# When importing a 'torch.utils.data.graph_settings' package, it shows that the package does not exist

Tags: python, torch, modulenotfounderror

The project is about the paper: [*EfficientViT: Lightweight Multi-Scale Attention for High-Resolution Dense Prediction*](https://github.com/mit-han-lab/efficientvit)

when I use this package：
`import to.utils.data.graph_settings`
It show that
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.data.graph_settings'`. When I use `pip install` and `conda install`, they cannot find this package.and when I click the `graph_settings`, it show that it cannot find declaration to go to.
I also search the pytorch.org website, it also can not find this function, so what can i do?

*The relevant code and comments are as follows*

```py
# For BC, use default SHARDING_PRIORITIES
torch.utils.data.graph_settings.apply_sharding(datapipe, total_workers, global_worker_id)
```